# Could I say "It interests me to do something"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I know "st interests me" & "It interests me + clause.".
example:

`Sports interests me.
It interests me how old you are.`

But I want to know could I use "It interest me to do something?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say it either way, however in your first example it would be "sports interest me" (not "interests") since sports are plural. In your final example of "it interest me to do something", it should be "interests" because "it" is singular. As a matter of communication, I would stick with the direct "sports interest me" because it's more concise and direct.

Comment: Thanks, I also have an advance question that if I could say "It interests me to play baseball." ?

Comment: That's grammatically correct, but awkward. Try "playing baseball interests me", or "I am interested in playing baseball". Decide whether you are the subject or object and construct your sentence accordingly.